# ejabberd MAM doesn't work with Strophe js

Tags: javascript, xml, ejabberd, strophe

I am trying to show the conversation between the two users even after the users logout and login. I mean when user1 logged out and again logged in, he should see the conversations made with the user2. I am using Ejabberd XMPP server and Strophe Js to retrive the messages.

As I found this [strophe.mam.js](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/mam) plugin to do this but raising the error and cant get the messages.

Here is my code:

```
function onConnect(status)
    {
        // Functions runs while users trys to login to the XMPP server
        var iq = null;

        switch (status)
        {
            case Strophe.Status.CONNECTING:
                log('Connecting.');
                break;
            case Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL:
                log('Failed to connect.');
                $('#connect').get(0).value = 'connect';
                break;
            case Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING:
                log('Disconnecting.');
                break;
            case Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED:
                log('Disconnected.');
                $('#connect').get(0).value = 'connect';
                break;
            case Strophe.Status.CONNECTED:
                log('Connected.');
                connection.addHandler(onMessage, null, 'message', null, null,  null);
                connection.addHandler(onPresence, null, 'presence', null, null, null);

                iq = $iq({type: 'get'}).c('query', {xmlns: 'jabber:iq:roster'});
                connection.sendIQ(iq, onRoster);

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

function onMessage(msg) {
    debugger;
    var fromJid = msg.getAttribute("from"),
        bareFromJid = Strophe.getBareJidFromJid(fromJid),
        type = msg.getAttribute("type"),
        elems = msg.getElementsByTagName("body");

    if (type == "chat" && elems.length > 0) {
        var body = elems[0],
            message = Strophe.getText(body);

        showMessage(bareFromJid + ": " + message);
              connection.mam.query("yashwanth@localhost", {
  "with": bareFromJid,
  onMessage: function(message) {
            console.log("Message from " + bareFromJid,
                ": " + message);
            return true;
  },
  onComplete: function(response) {
            console.log("Got all the messages");
  }
    });
    }

    return true;
}

function send() {
    // Handles with sending the message
    var to = $('#to-jid').get(0).value,
        myBareJid = Strophe.getBareJidFromJid(connection.jid);
        message = $('#message').get(0).value,
        reply = $msg({to: to, type: 'chat'})
            .c("body")
            .t(message);

    connection.send(reply.tree());
    showMessage(myBareJid + ": " + message);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE);
    messagebox = $("#messages");
    messagebox.val("");
    logbox = $("#log-messages");
    logbox.val("");
    rosterbox = $("#roster");
    rosterbox.val("");
    connection.rawInput = function (data) { log('RECV: ' + data); };
    connection.rawOutput = function (data) { log('SEND: ' + data); };

    Strophe.log = function (level, msg) { log('LOG: ' + msg); };

    login();
    $('#send').bind('click', send);
});
```

So whenever the user receives the message there will be something in the console. But it returns me this error in my logs

```
RECV: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><iq xmlns='jabber:client' 
from='yashwanth@localhost' to='yashwanth@localhost/22064184271436881211352579' 
id='yashwanth@localhost' type='error'><query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:0'><x xmlns='jabber:x:data'><field 
var='FORM_TYPE'><value>urn:xmpp:mam:0</value></field><field var='with'>
<value>shabda@localhost</value></field></x><set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'/></query>
<error code='400' type='modify'><bad-request xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error>
</iq></body>
```

Please help me out with this

Comment: Is archiving enabled either in ejabberd configuration or by the user for a given session ?

Comment: @Mickaël It is enabled in Ejabberd configuration and this plugins checks if the server is supporting the MAM

Comment: Can you show how it is configured in ejabberd ? What I mean is that archiving of message may not enabled as default even if module is enabled. The feature may be available, but no archiving required either by client or server.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond  `mod_mam:`
 `default: always`
`db_type: odbc `. In this way I have configured in ejabberd to save the chat history.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond I exactly needed this feature to retrive the messages. Check lines from [L26](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/blob/master/mod_archive/README.txt#L26).

Comment: I am confused, as you are pointing to mod_archive, which is implementing a different XEP, not MAM.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond Fine. Lets make it clear. I want to retrive messages of 1 to 1 chat between two users after logout and login. XEP-0313 archives the messages and XEP-0136 archives and retrives the messages. So  enabling MAM in ejabberd doesnt works for me. And I just pointed  mod_archive to let you know what i want exactly. I exactly needed is retriving the messages between the users when they logged in again. Its so helpful if we have chat in mail. My mail yashwanthbabu.gujarathi@gmail.com.. i am roadblocked at this archive stuff and needed your help

Comment: Please, look at ejabberd log in debug mode and post a link to the log. You have something wrong in your configuration and do not provide enough information to understand what is incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83428/discussion-between-yashwanth-and-mickael-remond).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MAM query is not correctly formatted.

You are missing the attribute `type="submit"` on the x element with xmlns `jabber:x:data` feature. Type is mandatory in [XEP-0004 Data Forms](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0004.html#protocol-formtypes)

You IQ should be:

```
<iq type='set' id='juliet1'>
  <query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:0'>
    <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
      <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'>
        <value>urn:xmpp:mam:0</value>
      </field>
      <field var='with'>
        <value>shabda@localhost</value>
      </field>
    </x>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

See Example 6 in [XEP-0313 Message Archive Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html#example-6).

The MAM strophe plugin had a bug. We prepared a fix here: https://github.com/processone/strophejs-plugins/commit/5a7857e2ab625c0521c68719d7e220f00c32c593

And submitted this pull request: https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/pull/65

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with MAM. See this link: https://www.ejabberd.im/forum/25028/solved-how-configure-and-test-modmam-message-archive-management

I solved the problem change type 'set' to 'get'

Comment: Then, the strophe.mam.v0.3.js will be:

query: function (jid, options) {
        var _p = this._p;
        var attr = {
            type:'get',
            id:jid
        };
        var mamAttr = {xmlns: Strophe.NS.MAM};
        if (!!options['queryid']) {
            mamAttr.queryid = options['queryid'];
            delete options['queryid'];
        }
        var iq = $iq(attr).c('query', mamAttr).c('x',{xmlns:'jabber:x:data', type:'submit'});